# Running a powershell script at startup

Tags: scheduled-tasks, powershell-3.0

I am writing a script to remove a computer from the domain, rename it, then add it back. It works fine when I set the trigger to AtLogOn but when I switch to AtStartUp I run into some issues.
I get this error when it restarts to run the first scheduled task:
0x8007051F: There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.
I suspect the script tries to run with no network connection set up so I tested using the RandomDelay parameter, and it worked like its suppose to.

I cant rely on a random delay so I am looking for an alternative. Is there a way to test the network status before the script begins or a way to delay the script a specific amount of time? I am using `Register-ScheduledJob` provided by Powershell 3.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use `Test-Connection` [cmdlet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/20/use-powershell-workflow-to-ping-computers-in-parallel.aspx) to ping a domain controller.  Loop until a  positive response is received.

Answer (score -1):

[Start-Sleep](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177002.aspx) with a if [Test-connection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849808.aspx) = $true against DC